# Changing the actual URL without changing display URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm new to htaccess so may be my question is silly.
My browser's address box is displaying

```
"***abc.com/jquery-charts/demos/1"
```

Now can I actually hit the link

```
"***abc.com/jquery-charts/"
```

without changing the display URL?
***abc.com is set in my localhost.

Comment: Yes, especially if you're running PHP. You can just execute any code you want based on the url, so it's up to you to make url two behave as url one.

Comment: Actually I'm getting a 404 for the first url. :(

Comment: But it's possible in htaccess too, see duplicate question for that.